# My Event SelectedIndexChanged dont work in my radcombobox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, telerik, radcombobox

I Have this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="RadCombobox2" ErrorMessage="Select One">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                   <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadCombobox2" EmptyMessage="Select One"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" PostBackUrl="frm.aspx"   EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

the point is that the event _SelectedIndexChanged is only triggered the first time , then back to no longer function .

Note that this control is inside a template editforms

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Make sure the values of the items are unique (e.g. the Id values).
Are there any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Also, do you change the item in the combo when "it doesn't work"? The event fires only when the chosen item has changed, not with each postback.